# Are iOS and Android Parental Control and ScreenTime APIs available to develop an app?

Tags: android, ios, swift, parental-control

I need some information on parental control apps on iOS and Android. May I please if we can develop a parental control app for the iPhone like controlling the apps usage or blocking the apps from another app? And as well can we do that in Android?

Does Apple allow such kind of apps to be submitted in stores? Do we have any public APIs for app development?

How can we develop such an app if we need to develop? Please provide some knowledge.

Example apps: FamilyTime

Comment: There are no APIs in iOS for this purpose. Many parental control apps implement MDM functionality to provide parental controls, however you require specific approval from Apple for this.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. So, do we need to write to apple for approval?

Comment: You will need to implement an MDM server. This needs a certificate. If the option to generate the required certificate is disabled in your developer account then you need to contact them; https://medium.com/developerinsider/how-to-create-a-verified-ios-mobile-device-management-mdm-profile-9d6739b92cc1

Comment: Great! Thanks @Paulw11. will be looking into those details.